# Using jquery for handling window resize event in Angular OnInt life cycle hook

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, resize

I am using JqxGrid Component in all of my pages in Angular 6 app. The problem I was solving was to resize jqxGrid to avaiable height on "browser window resize event". As jqxGrid doesn't do it on it's own and have no functionality provided for this. i solved it using below jquery event handler and TS code.

```
 $(window).resize( _.debounce( () => {
      this.myAccounts = [];
      setTimeout( () => {
        this.gridHeight = this.utilService.calculateGridHeight();
        this.myAccounts = this.source.localdata;
      }, 50);
    }, 100 ) );
```

what i want to ask is, As JqxGrid is used to show different data models in each page/component, do i have to use this code in each component(those having jqxGrid as child) ngOnIt method to react to window resize? or is there any other Angular way to achieve this? and is using jquery inside angular considered bad practice?

Thanks

Comment: Using jquery inside angular is considered bad practice ;)

Comment: @tomvangreen Any suggestions on how can i do this task in Angular then?

Comment: main problem is it is spread across multiple components

Comment: I would probably separate your concerns. Create a service that is responsible for tracking the page height. You could expose the page height via an observable in this service. Then in your components you can add a dependency to your height service and subscribe to changes. If you don't want to repeat yourself too much in your components, you could create a baseclass, where everything related to the height is implemented. But it is really hard to be more specific with the information you provided. Maybe have a look at the rxjs function `fromEvent` which converts dom events to rxjs streams.